# How to remove too big spacing before par-command?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I am writing an article and have a following issue with the LaTeX. I placed "par"-command and the spacing before the paragraph increased badly. I tried without "par", just by pressing Enter two times and got the same result. Could anyone explain me why is that and how to overcome this?
Thank you in advance.
[image: Too big spacing]

Comment: you should almost never use `\par` in a document ( a blank line is the same thing and the standard syntax). Presumably you (or your document class) have specified `\flushbottom` and have put something at the top of the next page that does not fit so tex has to stretch this page. either fix whatever is on the next page, or use `\raggedbottom`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As much as I remember I did not specified flushbottom. But I will check soon if I am wrong.

Comment: most classes specify flushbottom if they are two-side or two-column or "book" this is the vertical equivalent of justifying text where white space between words will stretch if you use words that can not be hyphenated.

Comment: Thank you. I am very new with LaTeX, so some details I don't know.